# 16 bit hex string to signed int in Java

Tags: java, parsing, signed, hex

I have a string in Java representing a signed 16-bit value in HEX. This string can by anything from `"0000"` to `"FFFF"`.

I use `Integer.parseInt("FFFF",16)` to convert it to an integer. However, this returns an unsigned value (`65535`).

I want it to return a signed value. In this particular example `"FFFF"` should return `-1`.

How can I achieve this? Since its a 16-bit value I thought of using `Short.parseShort("FFFF",16)` but that tells me that I am out of range. I guess `parseShort()` expects a negative sign.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can cast the `int` returned from `Integer.parseInt()` to a short:

```
short s = (short) Integer.parseInt("FFFF",16);
System.out.println(s);
```

Result:

```
-1
```

Comment: @AndreasFester , why does this require further cast as short?

Comment: @Rachael Because the value returned by `Integer.parseInt` is still a (32 bit) `int` value - for `0xFFFF`, that is `65535`. By assigning it to a `short`, the upper 16 bits are effectively discarded and bit 15 is taken as the  sign bit for the short value, resulting in `-1` (all bits are 1). The cast is required to tell the compiler that this loss of bits is intended - without the cast, the compiler would complain about `possible lossy conversion from int to short`

Comment: @AndreasFester thank you for that great explanation.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
int i = (short) Integer.parseInt("FFFF", 16);
```