# Not getting proper value into int from byte value

Tags: java, android

I am getting data from bluetooth and want to convert byte value to int and show result into float for that I have written following code

```
String prob1Str = manufactureData.substring(20, 24); // prob1Str = FE70

float prob1Temp =  (Integer.parseInt(prob1Str,16)&0xffff); // Here I am getting prob1Tem = 65136.0 instead of -400.0
model.setProb1Temp(prob1Temp);
```

From above code I am getting **prob1Tem = 65136.0** instead of **-400.0**

can anybody help me how to resolve this

thanks

Comment: `prob1Str = FE70` You are calling that a byte value. But actually you have a string with the hexadecimal representation of two bytes values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast your result to short!

```
float prob1Temp = (short)Integer.parseInt(prob1Str, 16);
```

int is 32 bits, so 0x0000FE70 = 65136, it is a positive value!

Short is 16 bits, 0xFE70 = -400, you will recast it to int or float after.

Look at [that explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202958/16-bit-hex-string-to-signed-int-in-java) for more details.

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range for short: "FE70"

Comment: float prob1Temp =  (Short.parseShort(prob1b+prob1a,16)&0xffff);

Comment: Thank you so much jbaptperez

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer.parseInt("FE70", 16) << 16 >> 16
```

will correctly extend sign bit. or same less tricky and not bound to Integer size:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt("FE70", 16);
if (i >= 0x8000) i -= 0x10000;
```